# How to register as singleton or transient all types implements one interface with StructureMap

Tags: dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, ioc-container, structuremap, structuremap3

I have two interfaces that says if a service have to be singleton or transient:

```
public interface ITransient {}
public interface ISingleton {}
```

I implement this interfaces in other interfaces and classes:

```
public interface ISession : ISingleton
{
    int? UserId {get;set;}
}

public class Session : ISession
{
    public int? UserId {get;set;}
}
```

Then I inject Session in others services:

```
public interface IBookService : ITransient
{
    ...
}

public class BookService : IBookService
{
    public BookService(ISession session) { ... }
    ...
}
```

How to configure StructureMap to make that all instance requests of types that implements ISingleton have to create with Singleton lifecycle??

I have tried it:

```
Container.Configure(conf => {
    conf.For<ITransient>().Transient();
    conf.For<ISingleton>().Singleton();
}
```

But nothing ... don't work, create a Session object as Transient.

I have tried it too:

```
        Container.Configure(conf =>
        {
            conf.Scan(s =>
            {
                s.Assembly(assembly);
                s.LookForRegistries();

                s.AddAllTypesOf<ISingletonDependency>();
                s.AddAllTypesOf<ITransientDependency>();
            });

            conf.For<ITransientDependency>().Transient();
            conf.For<ISingletonDependency>().Singleton();
        });
```

And nothing ...

I have seen how to do it using Windsor Castle:

```
        context.IocContainer.Register(
            Classes.FromAssembly(context.Assembly)
                .IncludeNonPublicTypes()
                .BasedOn<ITransient>()
                .WithService.Self()
                .WithService.DefaultInterfaces()
                .LifestyleTransient()
        );

        //Singleton
        context.IocContainer.Register(
            Classes.FromAssembly(context.Assembly)
                .IncludeNonPublicTypes()
                .BasedOn<ISingleton>()
                .WithService.Self()
                .WithService.DefaultInterfaces()
                .LifestyleSingleton()
```

But I don't know how to do using StructureMap ...

Other posibility is using conventions (IRegistrationConvention), but I don't know how to do, example:

```
    public class LifecycleConvention : IRegistrationConvention
    {
        public void Process(Type type, Registry registry)
        {
            if (type.GetInterface(typeOf(ISingleton) != null)
                **???? what to do ??!!**
        }
    }
```

Somebody can help me please?

**UPDATE**

I have build a convention:

```
public class BasicConvention : IRegistrationConvention
{
    public void Process(Type type, Registry registry)
    {
        if (!type.IsAbstract && typeof(ISingleton).IsAssignableFrom(type))
        {
            registry.For(type, new SingletonLifecycle());
        }
        if (!type.IsAbstract && typeof(ITransient).IsAssignableFrom(type))
        {
            registry.For(type, new TransientLifecycle());
        }
    }
}
```

And that seem work but it register each class as plugin type, in this case:

Session => Session [Singleton]
BookService => BookService [Transient]

But if I inject the Session as ISession ... don't found the instance due to ISession is not registered ... But I can use default convetions ... and then work BUT retrieve the instance as transient ...

Calling WhatDoIHave() I can see it:

```
===============================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================
PluginType                  Namespace                          Lifecycle     Description                                                                                                                                               Name                                    
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
....
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ISession                     Paf.Application.Session            Transient     Paf.Application.Session ('Paf.Application.Session, Paf.Modules.Core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null')                        Paf.Application.Session,... (Default)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
.....
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Session                     Paf.Application                    Singleton     Paf.Application.Session                                                                                                                                (Default)                               
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
...
===============================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================
```

Can I solve this it?

Comment: You are currently the abstraction with a lifestyle, but I think this is the wrong approach, since it is the implementation that determines its lifestyle, not the abstraction. In other words: your [abstraction leaks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaky_abstraction) which is a violation of the [Dependency Inversion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle).

Comment: True, true, ... then is "Session" (the implementation) who should implement "ISingleton" instead of "ISession", true?

Comment: Yep, or you mark it with an attribute (which seems more natural to me in this case). btw, why does `BookService` depend on `Session` instead of `ISession`. Is that an error? I think that is an accidental [Short Circuited Dependency](https://simpleinjector.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=ShortCircuitedDependencies).

Comment: Ok, I think using the attribute is a good way. Thanks!!
Yes, it should be ISession, I'm going to edit my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have gone to StructureMap sources to see how to work the default contention.

I found DefaultConventionScanner class:

```
public class DefaultConventionScanner : ConfigurableRegistrationConvention
{
    public override void Process(Type type, Registry registry)
    {
        if (!type.IsConcrete()) return;

        var pluginType = FindPluginType(type);
        if (pluginType != null && type.HasConstructors())
        {
            registry.AddType(pluginType, type);
            ConfigureFamily(registry.For(pluginType));
        }
    }

    public virtual Type FindPluginType(Type concreteType)
    {
        var interfaceName = "I" + concreteType.Name;
        return concreteType.GetInterfaces().FirstOrDefault(t => t.Name == interfaceName);
    }
}
```

I can deduce that I could change the plugin type registration (*registry.AddType(pluginType, type) line of code*) and write it:

```
            if(typeof(ISingleton).IsAssignableFrom(type))
                registry.For(pluginType).Use(type).Singleton();
            else if (typeof(ITransient).IsAssignableFrom(type))
                registry.For(pluginType).Use(type).Transient();
            else
            {
                registry.AddType(pluginType, type);
            }
            ConfigureFamily(registry.For(pluginType));
```

Ergo, if the pluginType (interface type) is ISingleton or ITransient I registry the new plugin type as Singleton or Transient otherwise registry the pluginType as allwais.

I have try and **know work**!! yeah!

Only one consideration, I don't know if exists some diference between:

```
            registry.AddType(pluginType, type);
```

and:
                registry.For(pluginType).Use(type);

I have compare the results of *WhaDoIHave()* before and after, and I can see a only one difference.

Old result:

```
===============================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================
PluginType                  Namespace                          Lifecycle     Description                                                                                                                                               Name                                    
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ISession                    Paf.Application.Session            Transient     Paf.Application.Session ('Paf.Application.Session, Paf.Modules.Core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null')                              Paf.Application.Session,... (Default)
===============================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================
```

New result:

```
===============================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================
PluginType                  Namespace                          Lifecycle     Description                                                                                                                                               Name                                    
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ISession                    Paf.Application.Session            Singleton     Paf.Application.Session                                                                                                                                (Default)                               
===============================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================
```

The new result is Ok, is Singleton, the diference is only in description, I think is no important think.

## UPDATE

According to [conversation with Steve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25334345/how-to-register-as-singleton-or-transient-all-types-implements-one-interface-wit?noredirect=1#comment39503362_25334345) in the comments of my question, I have decide not use ITransient and ISingleton interfaces. I have decided to use Attributes in the implementation classes.

I've created 2 attributes:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
public class SingletonLifecycleAttribute : Attribute
{
}
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
public class TransientLifecycleAttribute : Attribute
{
}
```

And I've assiged its to my classes:

```
public interface ISession   {       int? UserId {get;set;}  }

[SingletonLifecycle]
public class Session : ISession {       public int? UserId {get;set;}   }   

public interface IBookService { ... }

[TransientLifecycle]
public class BookService : IBookService { public BookService(ISession session) { ... }  }
```

Then I have modified my convention:

```
public class BasicConvention : ConfigurableRegistrationConvention
{
    public override void Process(Type type, Registry registry)
    {
        if (!type.IsConcrete()) return;

        var pluginType = FindPluginType(type);
        if (pluginType != null && type.HasConstructors())
        {
            var ci = registry.For(pluginType).Use(type);
            if (type.GetCustomAttributes(true).FirstOrDefault(a => a is TransientLifecycleAttribute) != null)
                ci.Transient();
            if (type.GetCustomAttributes(true).FirstOrDefault(a => a is SingletonLifecycleAttribute) != null)
                ci.Singleton();             
            ConfigureFamily(registry.For(pluginType));
        }
    }

    public virtual Type FindPluginType(Type concreteType)
    {
        var interfaceName = "I" + concreteType.Name;
        return concreteType.GetInterfaces().FirstOrDefault(t => t.Name == interfaceName);
    }
}
```

I think all is now fine and better ;)
Thanks Steve!